# Resizing Icons for mobile view with Jquery theme roller for mobile

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, icons, jquery-mobile-themeroller

I rolled a theme using jQuery mobile's theme roller but if I use the icons incited of text, the icons are too small, how can I make larger icons with theme roller? or any Idea how I can make larger icons?

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 480px) {

.ui-icon-bars02:after {
  background-image: url("images.svg");

  background-size: 22px 22px;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest adding an explanation of the code so OP could benefit and gain knowledge from your answer.